# How to execute a stored procedure with date in adsweb

Tags: stored-procedures, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in a http call to adsweb. The procedure calls for a date and a string.
if i enter:

```
GetBalance?todate='2018-03-15'&phone='9999999'
```

I get a:
Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 07006;   NativeError = 2109;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Conversion error

How would I enter the date?
It works fine in Arc32
Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this a lot in the past so I know it works.  Usually problems are due to special characters in the URI.  First of all, don't include any actual quote characters in the URI string like you have in your example.

For example the URI would just be:

```
GetBalance?todate=2018-03-15&phone=9999999
```

The adsweb module parser will split the procedure arguments on the & character so you don't need to use quotes.

Also if you have parameter data with special characters like quotes or percents, you need to encode them prior to sending and the module will decode them for you.  I use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in javascript to encode them.

Comment: Thanks I thought I tried it but I will try again on Monday.

Comment: Sometimes I get this error: {
    "error": {
        "code": "7200",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5154;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 5154:  Execution of the stored procedure failed.  ProcError 7200:   AdsQuery1: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2124;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator: <= [Invalid DATE] -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 53 (line: 2 column: 30)"
        }
    }
}

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bad date value.  Like it was missing leading zeros in the day or month portion.  I would try logging the date value (or entire URL) you used when an error occurs.  I bet that would help explain the problem.  You might even be able to find it in the Apache access log if you know what time it occurred.